# I can't use triggers to update a column based on changes in another column

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to automatically update the value of `AdoptionDate` every time `AdopterID` receives a value different from NULL. I tried to do this using the code below, but it gives me Error Code: 1362.

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `Assignment`;
CREATE SCHEMA `Assignment` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
USE `Assignment`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Dog`;
CREATE TABLE `Dog` (
    `DogID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Race` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `RescueDate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `AdoptionDate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    `AdopterID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`DogID`)
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER CustomTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON `Dog`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`AdopterID` <=> NULL THEN
        SET NEW.`AdoptionDate` = NOW();
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Use ```<>``` instead of ```<=>```

Comment: Or instead of ```NEW.`AdopterID` <=> NULL``` use ```NOT NEW.`AdopterID` IS NULL```